# Replace all strings containing a sub string with an anchor tag in Jquery and the href attribute should be the actual string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page. From that page, I need to find out all strings containing a substring and wrap an anchor tag around all of them with href attribute to the main string.

Example :

### Input

this is the input and here substring is "Nihir"

```
<h1>Nihir is NihirMandowara</h2>
<p>NihirRMan is here</p>
<h2>Nihirjlkjlkj is there</h2>
```

### Output

in the o/p, i need to add href tag

```
<h1>
  <a href="Nihir">Nihir</a> is <a  href="NihirMandowara">NihirMandowara</a>           </h2>
<p><a href="NihirRMan">NihirRMan</a> is here</p>
<h2>
  <a href="Nihirjlkjlkj">Nihirjlkjlkj</a> is there
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll have to be a loop. Once you've loaded your file, put it through this function:

```
function Linkify(input, prefix)
{
    var output = "";
    while (input.indexOf(prefix) >= 0)
    {
        output += input.substr(0, input.indexOf(prefix));
        input = input.substr(input.indexOf(prefix), input.length - input.indexOf(prefix));
        var l = input.indexOf(" ");
        if (input.indexOf("<") < l) l = input.indexOf("<");
        if (l < 0) l = input.length + 1;
        output += "<a href=\"" + input.substr(0, l - 1) + "\">" + input.substr(0, l - 1) + "</a>";
        input = input.substr(l, input.length - l);
    }
    output += input;
    return output;
}
```

This assumes that your strings begin with the prefix you're passing in and terminates with a space or a `<`.

Let me know if it works, I wrote it on my phone!